# Ta-lib package on Google App Engine Standard Python 3 using requirements.txt

Tags: google-app-engine, python-3.7, ta-lib

Every time I try to deploy to app engine, I get a build failure for [ta-lib](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib). The logging trace has a few lines like:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I've deployed on app engine flexible before using docker and a [ta-lib wheel](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib) but I couldn't get the wheel to work with standard enviroment, so trying ta-lib directly in requirements.txt. My project runs fine locally.
I thought maybe it's because requirements.txt doesn't install Numpy first or something. My app.yaml is simple:

```
runtime: python37
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

Is it possible to use ta-lib on app engine standard environment Python 3.7?

Any help would be most appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Here is my requirements.txt file:

```
numpy==1.18.1
pandas==1.0.1
Flask
marshmallow
pytz
requests
python-dateutil
flask-cors
python-dotenv
python-jose-cryptodome
six
cryptocompare
ta-lib==0.4.17
```

Comment: Could you please attach your requirements.txt file?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @NibrassH. I have added the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to consider that dependencies for [Python applications on App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/specifying-dependencies) are declared in a standard **requirements.txt** file.

> When you deploy to App Engine, the dependencies specified in the
>   **requirements.txt** file will be installed automatically with your
>   deployed app

[Also regarding **requirements.txt**](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#requirements-files)

> “Requirements files” are files containing a list of items to be
>   installed using pip install like so:
>
> ```
> pip install -r requirements.txt
> ```
>
> Details on the format of the files are
>   here: Requirements File Format.
>
> Logically, a Requirements file is just a list of pip install arguments
>   placed in a file. Note that you should not rely on the items in the
>   file being installed by pip in any particular order.

However, the process of installing `ta-lib python module` consists of:

1.Install underlying TA-Lib C library.

2.Install python dependencies (numpy or pandas, etc.)

3.Install ta-lib python module

Therefore I do not think you can use this module for App Engine Standard. I think you should consider using App Engine Flexible or Cloud Run.

This is a tutorial on how to [Install ta-lib in python 3.7](https://medium.com/@joelzhang/install-ta-lib-in-python-3-7-51219acacafb) with a sample `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.7
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN pip install numpy
RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install sqlalchemy
# TA-Lib
RUN wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
 tar -xvzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
 cd ta-lib/ && \
 ./configure — prefix=/usr && \
 make && \
 make install && \
 cd .. && \
 wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/90/05/d4c6a778d7a7de0be366bc4a850b4ffaeac2abad927f95fa8ba6f355a082/TA-Lib-0.4.17.tar.gz && \
 tar xvf TA-Lib-0.4.17.tar.gz && \
 cd TA-Lib-0.4.17 && \
 python setup.py install && \
 cd ..
RUN rm -R ta-lib ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz TA-Lib-0.4.17 TA-Lib-0.4.17.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @marian.vladoi. I thought this might be the case. I have previously deployed successfully to Flexible Environment. I hoped there might be a way to do it in Standard Environment since they started allowing 3rd party Python modules written in C. I'll wait until the bounty concludes and award you the points if no one else some how comes up with a way to do it.