# TA-Lib not installed while using it with Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ta-lib

I have specified TA-Lib in my requirements.txt file. Google App Engine tries to install the requirement but leads to following error. Kindly guide how to use TA-Lib with Google App Engine

```
 talib/_ta_lib.c:747:10: fatal error: ta-lib/ta_defs.h: No such file or directory
   #include "ta-lib/ta_defs.h"
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
  [end of output]

 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for TA-Lib
Building wheel for breeze-connect (setup.py): started
Building wheel for breeze-connect (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Created wheel for breeze-connect: filename=breeze_connect-1.0.36-py3-none-any.whl size=22216sha256=d03764120328198bc9a534b85698428865ae0cb02f4731aaaeba7d16f4fea92c
Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-na97wk4a/wheels/15/7d/7  6/4fd7f3c79bd7b7229329b94e5de2fc8ebff50be4fb15cac6ff
Failed to build TA-Lib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for TA-Lib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
Full build logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds;region=us-west1/d5e73467-0f3a-46aa-ba5d-2f752ca0ff44?project=78334536755
```

Comment: As per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60836147/18265570), if you are using `App Engine Standard` this module is not supported. Consider using `Flexible` environment.